# Make a Text File Using Laravel and PHP

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I want to ask a question. I'm new in laravel framework. I want to create a text file from the input form data user using the Laravel framework. while the same time, I want to save these input to my database.

I have success to save in my database. but I fail to create the .txt file from this.

I have tried to get data from database but error. and I just try to get data from input form is an error too.

I've tried...

```
<?php

    $nama     = $_POST['name'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $dob      = $_POST['date'];
    $phone    = $_POST['phone'];
    $gender   = $_POST['gender'];
    $address  = $_POST['addreess'];
    $date     = date('dmY');
    $jam      = data('his');

    $data = "$nama,$email,$dob,$phone,$gender,$address";
    $file = "$nama"-"$date$jam";
    $namafile = "$file.txt";  

    $fh = fopen($namafile,"w");  
    fwrite($fh,$data);

    fclose($file);  

    echo "<h2>Hasil Penyimpanan Data</h2>";  
    echo "<hr>";  
    echo "Hasil : <a href='$namafile'> $namafile </a>";
```

I use it in my index.php with the means that I can get data from the input form directly and then save as a .txt file.

Here's my code in the controller that's saving to my database:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $employee = new Employee();
    $employee->nama = $request->get('name');
    $employee->email = $request->get('email');
    $employee->dob = $request->get('date');
    $employee->phone = $request->get('phone');
    $employee->gender = $request->get('gender');
    $employee->addreess = $request->get('addreess');
    $employee->save();

    return redirect('employees')->with('success','Selamat, Data berhasil di tambahkan !');
}
```

How can I save the input data to the database and at the same time how can I save the data to a text file?

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Do one thing, then do the second thing, *then* return the redirect. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#storing-files for the Laravel way of working with files. If you want more help than that, let us know what "but error" means, like the error message and the lines of code that cause it.

Comment: Your filename won't be correct, since that's not how you concatenate. It might also be better to specify which directory you want to place it in, whether it's storage or public.

Comment: actually i don't know where i have to put the syntax that i can save to txt file. i use that code in php native and in Codeogniter is work. when i use laravel, i confused how i can save the data to text file @ceejayoz

Comment: @MuhammadSholehhudin Do it after you `->save()` the Employee record. Why are you even creating a file, though? You've got everything in the database already.

Comment: can i save this form to the txt file ? so this is the requirement from my bos.. i have to save the information form to the text file.. @ceejayoz

Comment: Yes, you can. I've linked you to the docs on how to create a file and save text into it. (It's still a silly requirement; what's the point of storing it both in a .txt and in the database?)

Comment: i've tried to put it below  ->save()  but it still error. it says "fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given" . what i should to change it to be string..hmm yaa you know, the bos is always true in any situation.. @ceejayoz

Comment: You shouldn't be using functions like `fclose`. I linked you to the docs on Laravel's file functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Laravel, use put() of Storage facade.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Your content here');

// 'file.txt' // yo can use your file name here.
// 'Your content here' // you can specify your content here
```

This will be stored in `storage/app/`

so your controller will look like this,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Employee;


class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Your content here');

      $employee = new Employee();
      $employee->nama = $request->get('name');
      $employee->email = $request->get('email');
      $employee->dob = $request->get('date');
      $employee->phone = $request->get('phone');
      $employee->gender = $request->get('gender');
      $employee->addreess = $request->get('addreess');
      $employee->save();

      return redirect('employees')->with('success','Selamat, Data berhasil di tambahkan !');
    }

}
```

Comment: where i should take this syntax ? in controller or route ? or any else ? i still newbie at all laravel.. @Sobin

Comment: @MuhammadSholehhudin no worries, I can help you, you can add this code in your controller, but this will go at the top use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Comment: Oke thankyou so much.. if you can guide me to clear this exercise. then where i add the Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Your content here'); ? below my Storage() method ? or i have to create a new method and write in that ? @SobinAugustine

Comment: No, you can add both in the same method store(), if it's has to happen in the same process.

Comment: So, this code is still working or not ? about how i create these data to txt file ? i means the first code that i share above @SobinAugustine

Comment: Step 1: do Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Your content here');

Comment: after checking step 1 do Step 2: add your logic to file name and file content

Comment: Step 3 : implement the eloquent save

Comment: So, my logic about file name and content is still in Controller ? with Storage method ? @SobinAugustine

Comment: Hey, you know, im just success to creating a file.. but its only one time.. then i fill the form again, the text file is not created..

Comment: @MuhammadSholehhudin yes, with store() method

Comment: @MuhammadSholehhudin thats because it's again overwriting the file, so give unique names(include timestamp in file name logic etc), that will solve the issue.

Comment: Yaa, you were right.. now this is work for me..i can add if the input name is different or after refreshing..hehe btw thank you so much before.. but there is one function doesnt working yet..  [$date     = date('dmY'); $jam      = data('his');] i can't do this code in my controller because controller doesn't extend bootstrap datepicker.. how can i get the value of the time now ? @SobinAugustine